# How to remove environment variables at the end of a loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, environment-variables, proxies

My code runs in a while loop and at one point needs to use proxies like this:

```
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "http://195.154.XXX.XXX:XXX01"
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://195.154.XXX.XXX:XXX01"
```

When the new loop starts, however, I need to remove these `os.environ` changes or else the program doesn't work.

How could I do that? And yes, I NEED to use `os.environ` to make the second part of the code work.

Comment: Call `del os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"]` and `del os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"]` when you no longer need them.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)? There is says "You can delete items in this mapping to unset environment variables. `unsetenv()` will be called automatically when an item is deleted from `os.environ`, and when one of the `pop()` or `clear()` methods is called."